# Android resource linking failed

Tags: java, android-studio

Делал приложение на Android studio, вроде в коде ошибок нет, но при по пытке запуска выдает:

```
Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\alice\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\5d8be95ef6bf0f2be2678324efa04335\transformed\androidx.appcompat\drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi-v17_abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png.flat: error: failed to read file: magic value is 0x00000000 but AAPT expects 0x54504141.
error: failed parsing overlays.
```

Не могу понять, с чем связана ошибка и как ее исправить

Answer (score 0):

В общем, проблема возникала из-за того, что gradle файлы были на Kotlin, если у кого-то схожая проблема - просто перестойте проект с другим gradle built.